# How do I print the index of the end of an aligned sequence?

Tags: python

I am using code to find where seq_find is located in seq_long and am trying to print out the index in seq_long where the alignment ends.

```
seq_long="CCGACATCGTCCTCACCGACCATCGTCCTGCATCGTCCT"
seq_find="CATCGTCCT"
matching_seq_index=[]
matching_seq_range=[]
matching_seq_index_end=[]
for x in range(len(seq_long)):
    search=seq_long[x:x+9]
    matched=[]
    if search==seq_find:
        matching_seq_index.append(x)
        matching_seq_index_range.append(len(search))
        matching_seq_index_end.append(x:x+len(search))
    else:
        pass
print matching_seq_index
```

Comment: And what exactly is the problem you are facing? Wrong output? Program crashes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change:

```
matching_seq_index_end.append(x:x+len(search))
```

to:

```
matching_seq_index_end.append(x+len(search))
```

Anyways a much shorter version using [`re.finditer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer) and a list comprehension:

```
>>> import re
>>> [m.end() for m in re.finditer(seq_find, seq_long)]
[13, 29, 39]
```

Comment: Ok, so I see where how that works to give me the last index of the alignment, but how do I continue through the sequence?  It now stops once it finds the first alignment.

Comment: @bk4488 I am getting `[13, 29, 39]` as output right now, what is your expected output? http://ideone.com/C7bTDe

Comment: Sorry, I had something changed in mine by mistake.  I get all three beginning and ending indices now.  Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you split `seq_long` with `seq_find` you find that how many time your `seq_find` repeated in `seq_long` so with a simple code you can print out the index in seq_long where the alignment ends. :

```
>>> seq_long.split(seq_find)
['CCGA', 'CACCGAC', 'G', '']

>>> [end_sign[0] if len(end_sign)>0 else '' for end_sign in seq_long.split(seq_find)]
['C', 'C', 'G', '']
```